# Can emacs run inside chrome?

Tags: osx

Can emacs be run in chrome? Like vim does at

https://rhysd.github.io/vim.wasm/

Comment: Spacemacs could run inside a browser. They had a try online button on their home page. So, I believe that it can run in a browser.

Comment: reading official webassembly docs, it says "Editors such as vim and emacs should just work...."

Comment: interesting tweet https://twitter.com/tpope/status/1016390013481832448

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, yes.

It was talked about a couple of year ago:

http://endlessparentheses.com/emacs-is-available-on-chromebook-and-chrome.html
https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/311kpk/emacs_runs_natively_on_chrome/

I tried it briefly then, but it was not clear how to configure it, so it was more of a curiosity. There does not seem to be any recent developments. I, too, would be interested in seeing how to run and configure emacs 26.1 in a current Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The Chrome app NaCL Development Enviroment includes Emacs.  In addition, the changes were [upstreamed into Emacs' configure.ac](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-03/msg00312.html) to add NaCL as a regular port.